# Sequelize and 2 join tables, trouble

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

We've got a problem. We cannot execute a SQL SELECT on below structure using sequelize.

This is our structure, see below image.

[image]

We are trying to execute this sequelize query:

```
query = {
    'attributes': [models.sequelize.fn('count', models.sequelize.col('sent_deals.user_id'))],


    order: [['alert.keywords', ' DESC']],
    attributes: ['alert.keywords'],
    include: [
        {
            model: models.alert,
            attributes: ['keywords']
        }, {
            where: {
                'products.sent_deal.created_at': {
                    between: [moment(start).startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'), moment(end).endOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')]
                }
            },
            model: models.product,
            attributes: ['id']
        }
    ]
};



models.userAlerts.findAll(query)
```

But then we receive the following error: `"error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "alert""`, because we're trying to select the attribute `alert.keywords` also outside the `include[]`, but still it DID work in the previous version of Sequelize JS! And now we cannot order by alert anymore.... :( It always returns ONE alert because of the "belongs to" connection, so theoretically it has to work.

My guess is because the query doesn't execute a direct join, but does a `SELECT FROM` on a subquery, see below:

```
SELECT "userAlerts".*
    ,"alert"."id" AS "alert.id"
    ,"alert"."keywords" AS "alert.keywords"
    ,"products"."id" AS "products.id"
    ,"products.sent_deal"."user_alert_id" AS "products.sent_deal.user_alert_id"
    ,"products.sent_deal"."deal_id" AS "products.sent_deal.deal_id"
    ,"products.sent_deal"."created_at" AS "products.sent_deal.created_at"
FROM (
    SELECT "userAlerts"."id"
        ,"userAlerts"."user_id"
        ,"userAlerts"."alert_id"
        ,"userAlerts"."activationToken"
        ,"userAlerts"."activatedAt"
        ,"userAlerts"."createdAt"
        ,"userAlerts"."updatedAt"
    FROM "user_alerts" AS "userAlerts"
    WHERE (
            SELECT "products.sent_deal"."user_alert_id"
            FROM "sent_deals" AS "products.sent_deal"
            INNER JOIN "deals" AS "products" ON "products"."id" = "products.sent_deal"."deal_id"
            WHERE "userAlerts"."id" = "products.sent_deal"."user_alert_id"
                AND (
                    "products.sent_deal"."created_at" BETWEEN '2014-11-17 00:00'
                        AND '2014-12-02 23:59'
                    ) LIMIT 1
            ) IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY "alert"."keywords" DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS "userAlerts"
LEFT JOIN "alerts" AS "alert" ON "alert"."id" = "userAlerts"."alert_id"
INNER JOIN (
    "sent_deals" AS "products.sent_deal" INNER JOIN "deals" AS "products" ON "products"."id" = "products.sent_deal"."deal_id"
    ) ON "userAlerts"."id" = "products.sent_deal"."user_alert_id"
    AND (
        "products.sent_deal"."created_at" BETWEEN '2014-11-17 00:00'
            AND '2014-12-02 23:59'
        )
ORDER BY "alert"."keywords" DESC
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having the `keywords` attribute on the include, should be enough, there is no need to add it to the outer query

```
attributes: [models.sequelize.fn('count', models.sequelize.col('sent_deals.user_id'))],


order: [['alert.keywords', ' DESC']],
attributes: ['alert.keywords'], <-- This line is superflous
include: [
    {
        model: models.alert,
        attributes: ['keywords']
    }, {
        where: {
            'products.sent_deal.created_at': { 
                between: [moment(start).startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'), moment(end).endOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')]
            }
        },
        model: models.product,
        attributes: ['id']
    }
]
```

Shouldn't you be including SentDeal in order to query products.sent_deal? This issue is probably better suite for an issue on the sequelize GH

Comment: For the reason: ...now we cannot order by alert anymore...
That's why we added (when we used the previous version of sequelize: 1.7.8) ```attributes: ['alert.keywords']```, so the alerts where visible in the top level of the object (containing the results) and not inside the "alert" object of the main object. So we could order all the results based on alert. Do you see what I mean? But the ```superflous``` line isn't working since we tried to upgrade to 2.0.0. And sent_deals is now a join table, we use to connect to it using a "through" inside the product and user_alerts model.

Comment: Small example, we want something like: ```{{alert:'test2'},{alert:'test1'}}```and not ```{{alert:{keywords:'test2'}},{alert:{keywords:'test1'}}}``` In 1.7.8 this worked, with the "superflous" line, but in 2.0.0 not anymore, it seems...